# How to use assert_frame_equal() for asserting all the values in the dataframe without exiting on failure

Tags: python, pandas, pytest, assert, assertion

I am a newbie to python and dataframes. I am currently trying to compare 2 dataframes with the `assert_frame_equal()` function .

```
df1=     a  b
      0  1  3
      1  2  4

df2=    a   b
      0  2  3.0
      1  2  4.0
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas._testing import assert_frame_equal
def test_compare_src_trg():
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 2], 'b': [3.0, 4.0]})
 pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

When this is run , the assertion fails at the first column as value "1" is not equal "2" which is correct. But I want the assertion to run on all items of dataframe and give the overall pass/fail results .

```
----------------------------------
raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="a") are different

DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="a") values are different (50.0 %)
[index]: [0, 1]
[left]:  [1, 2]
[right]: [2, 2]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It looks like your code is just run at top-level, rather than in a test function? Since you tagged this `pytest`, simply `def test_whatever():` should suffice, then call `pytest` to collect and execute them ...

Comment: Hi, I am using def test function for assertions. Though having it in the function, the assertion fails when the first dataframe value is different. What I am looking for is to run all the assertions though it fails at the first value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use something else like [`compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html). You can see the full comparison and assert if the resulting Dataframe is empty to check if they are equal.

```py
cp = df1.compare(df2)
#      a
#   self other
# 0  1.0   2.0

assert cp.empty, "Dataframes are not equal"
# AssertionError: Dataframes are not equal
```

Note

> Can only compare identically-labeled (i.e. same shape, identical row and column labels) DataFrames

Comment: Hi @Romain, My columns are not identical. I mean in the df2 , there might be n rows differing from df1.  Is there a way i can compare the 2 dataframes